# Why 2700 records (320KB each) should take 30 seconds to be fetched?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have 2700 records in `MongoDB`. Each document has a size of approximately 320KB. The engine I use is `wiredTiger` and the total size of collection is about 885MB.

My `MongoDB` config is as below:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
  engine: wiredTiger
  wiredTiger:
      engineConfig:
         cacheSizeGB: 1
         statisticsLogDelaySecs: 0
         journalCompressor: snappy
      collectionConfig:
         blockCompressor: snappy
      indexConfig:
         prefixCompression: false
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

My connection is via `socket`:

```
mongo_client = MongoClient('/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock')
```

And collection stats reveal this result:

```
db.mycol.stats()
{
    "ns" : "bi.mycol",
    "count" : 2776,
    "size" : 885388544,
    "avgObjSize" : 318944,
    "storageSize" : 972476416,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
        },
        "creationString" : "allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=0,checkpoint=(WiredTigerCheckpoint.9=(addr=\"01e30275da81e4b9e99f78e30275db81e4c61d1e01e30275dc81e40fab67d5808080e439f6afc0e41e80bfc0\",order=9,time=1444566832,size=511762432,write_gen=13289)),checkpoint_lsn=(24,52054144),checksum=uncompressed,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,id=5,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=1MB,memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=0,prefix_compression_min=4,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,value_format=u,version=(major=1,minor=1)",
        "type" : "file",
        "uri" : "statistics:table:collection-0-6630292038312816605",
        "LSM" : {
            "bloom filters in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "bloom filter false positives" : 0,
            "bloom filter hits" : 0,
            "bloom filter misses" : 0,
            "bloom filter pages evicted from cache" : 0,
            "bloom filter pages read into cache" : 0,
            "total size of bloom filters" : 0,
            "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle" : 0,
            "chunks in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "highest merge generation in the LSM tree" : 0,
            "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist" : 0,
            "sleep for LSM merge throttle" : 0
        },
        "block-manager" : {
            "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
            "blocks allocated" : 0,
            "checkpoint size" : 511762432,
            "allocations requiring file extension" : 0,
            "blocks freed" : 0,
            "file magic number" : 120897,
            "file major version number" : 1,
            "minor version number" : 0,
            "file bytes available for reuse" : 460734464,
            "file size in bytes" : 972476416
        },
        "btree" : {
            "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
            "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "column-store internal pages" : 0,
            "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
            "pages rewritten by compaction" : 0,
            "number of key/value pairs" : 0,
            "fixed-record size" : 0,
            "maximum tree depth" : 4,
            "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
            "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
            "maximum leaf page key size" : 3276,
            "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
            "maximum leaf page value size" : 1048576,
            "overflow pages" : 0,
            "row-store internal pages" : 0,
            "row-store leaf pages" : 0
        },
        "cache" : {
            "bytes read into cache" : 3351066029,
            "bytes written from cache" : 0,
            "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
            "unmodified pages evicted" : 8039,
            "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
            "modified pages evicted" : 0,
            "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 1,
            "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 1,
            "internal pages evicted" : 0,
            "pages split during eviction" : 0,
            "in-memory page splits" : 0,
            "overflow values cached in memory" : 0,
            "pages read into cache" : 10519,
            "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
            "pages written from cache" : 0
        },
        "compression" : {
            "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : 0,
            "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : 0,
            "raw compression call succeeded" : 0,
            "compressed pages read" : 10505,
            "compressed pages written" : 0,
            "page written failed to compress" : 0,
            "page written was too small to compress" : 0
        },
        "cursor" : {
            "create calls" : 7,
            "insert calls" : 0,
            "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls" : 0,
            "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted" : 0,
            "next calls" : 0,
            "prev calls" : 2777,
            "remove calls" : 0,
            "cursor-remove key bytes removed" : 0,
            "reset calls" : 16657,
            "search calls" : 16656,
            "search near calls" : 0,
            "update calls" : 0,
            "cursor-update value bytes updated" : 0
        },
        "reconciliation" : {
            "dictionary matches" : 0,
            "internal page multi-block writes" : 0,
            "leaf page multi-block writes" : 0,
            "maximum blocks required for a page" : 0,
            "internal-page overflow keys" : 0,
            "leaf-page overflow keys" : 0,
            "overflow values written" : 0,
            "pages deleted" : 0,
            "page checksum matches" : 0,
            "page reconciliation calls" : 0,
            "page reconciliation calls for eviction" : 0,
            "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression" : 0,
            "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression" : 0
        },
        "session" : {
            "object compaction" : 0,
            "open cursor count" : 7
        },
        "transaction" : {
            "update conflicts" : 0
        }
    },
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 208896,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 143360,
        "date_1" : 65536
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

How can I understand that MongoDB uses swap? How to infer where exactly is the bottleneck?

---

**EDIT:**

The way I fetch data in python is:

```
for doc in mycol.find({'date': {"$lte": '2016-12-12', '$gte': '2012-09-09'}}, {'_id': False}):
       doc['uids'] = set(doc['uids'])
       records.append(doc)
```

`date` field is indexed.

**EDIT 2:** 
These are the result when fetching data:

```
CPU core1: ~65%
CPU core2: ~65%
CPU core3: ~65%
CPU core4: ~65%
RAM: 7190/8190MB
swap: 1140/2048MB
```

---

**EDIT 3:**
MongoDB log is:

```
2015-10-11T17:25:08.317+0330 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from anonymous unix socket #18 (2 connections now open)
2015-10-11T17:25:08.321+0330 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from anonymous unix socket #19 (3 connections now open)
2015-10-11T17:25:36.501+0330 I QUERY    [conn19] getmore bi.mycol cursorid:10267473126 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:3 nreturned:14 reslen:4464998 locks:{} 199ms
2015-10-11T17:25:37.665+0330 I QUERY    [conn19] getmore bi.mycol cursorid:10267473126 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:5 nreturned:14 reslen:4464998 locks:{} 281ms
2015-10-11T17:25:50.331+0330 I NETWORK  [conn19] end connection anonymous unix socket (2 connections now open)
2015-10-11T17:25:50.363+0330 I NETWORK  [conn18] end connection anonymous unix socket (1 connection now open)
```

---

**EDIT 4:**
Sample data is:

```
{"date": "2012-09-12", "uids": [1,2,3,4,...,30000]}
```

**NB: I have 30k UIDs inside of `uids` field.**

---

**EDIT 5:**

Explaining query display that it has used `IXSCAN` stage:

```
$ db.mycol.find({'date': {"$lte": '2018-11-27', '$gte': '2011-04-23'}}, {'_id': 0}).explain("executionStats")
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "bi.mycol",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "date" : {
                        "$lte" : "2018-11-27"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date" : {
                        "$gte" : "2011-04-23"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "transformBy" : {
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "date" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "date_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "date" : [
                            "[\"2011-04-23\", \"2018-11-27\"]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 2776,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 2312,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 2776,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2776,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION",
            "nReturned" : 2776,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 540,
            "works" : 2777,
            "advanced" : 2776,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 0,
            "saveState" : 31,
            "restoreState" : 31,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "transformBy" : {
                "_id" : 0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "nReturned" : 2776,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 470,
                "works" : 2777,
                "advanced" : 2776,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 31,
                "restoreState" : 31,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 2776,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 2776,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 2776,
                    "advanced" : 2776,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needFetch" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 31,
                    "restoreState" : 31,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "date" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "date_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "date" : [
                            "[\"2011-04-23\", \"2018-11-27\"]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 2776,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                    "matchTested" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "MySys.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.0.0",
        "gitVersion" : "nogitversion"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

**EDIT 6:**

```
OS: Mac osX Yosemite
MongoDB version: 3.0.0
Total RAM: 8G
Filesystem: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
```

Comment: "How to infer where exactly is the bottleneck?" - Obviously by measuring everyhing relevant: CPU, memory, disk and network utilization. Check both server and client side.

Comment: Memory can be a bottleneck not only in terms of free space but also in maximum available troughput. Are you intending to leave 20 small comments here or are you going to do your homework and come back with the full results (update you question)?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath question is updated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1. Do you have index on date ? 2. Can you keep query outside the for loop and then fetch the result ?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. What do you mean? I need a cursor to traverse it and fetch data.

Comment: Erm, let me get that straight: you are complaining because a transfer of 885Mb  and the deserialization of 2776 elements takes 24 seconds? That's 8/1000 of a second on average for finding the documents position in the datafile in the index, reading the according document from disk, transfer and deserialize it. In my book, that's freaking fast. To further optimize that, I need more info. How big is your RAM, how much of it is used by mongod (and how much by other processes), what OS and filesystem are you using?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg read the `EDIT 6` part. The answer to how much RAM is used by `mongod` depends on Mongo itself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods I used to improve performance:

1. First of all instead of using for loop to traverse query and fetch data, I give the cursor to `Pandas` rather than creating a large list object in python:

   ```
   cursor = mycol.find({'date': {"$lte": end_date, '$gte': start_date}}, {'_id': False})
   df = pandas.DataFrame(list(cursor))
   ```

   Performance got much better it now takes 10 seconds at most rather than 30 seconds.
2. Instead of using `doc['uids'] = set(doc['uids'])` which take around 6 seconds I didn't change default list to set and handled duplicates with dataframe itself.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here:

1. Use isodate instead of string date for  faster index lookups, as string dates do a lexographic string comparison, whereas isodates does a numeric one.
   Since your total records are low, the type of index should not be a big problem, the problem might be size of documents and their network transfer plus deserialization.
2. Try a query with not selecting the uid field i.e.

   ```
   for doc in mycol.find({'date': {"$lte": '2016-12-12', '$gte': '2012-09-09'}}, {'_id': False,'uid':False}):
   ```

Your query time will improve by a huge margin.You will then need to investigate the transfer times between your application and mongodb servers, and also benchmark for single document fetching using `find_one()` to see how much time deserializations are taking.

Comment: We had `ISODate` at first but as we use `Jalali` date beside `Gregorian`.  `MongoDB` adds time offset to dates inserted we couldn't use it and its complex to explain it now. Your second solution does not solve the problem! because I need `uids` inside of my app. I know for sure that if I remove `uids` it speeds up query time in order of magnitude. Does horizontal scaling solve my problem?

Comment: @AlirezaHos removing uids is not the solution I mentioned, it is a way to track the real problem. If size of the documents is the real issue, you may need to benchmark your code for network time and deserialization time.

Comment: By `uids` took 39 seconds and without `uids` it took 1 second.

Comment: Could explain more about how to benchmark my code for network time and deserialization time?

Comment: @Alireza Hos Try sharding your data. It may possibly help you. Can u mention time taken for the first read and consequent reads.